# Drag and drop script works only once but stops working [No jQuery]

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I was making my own flexible javascript DnD script when I encountered an error. The div moves perfectly fine the first time, but the remaining times, it messes up the offset. I know what everyone is probably going to say; *"why don't you use a library?"*. The reason is because having my own personally designed script is easier to edit and understand. There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but here is the code:

```js
document.onmousemove = mouseCoords;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var cl1= false;
var time1= true;
var divid;
var offs1;
var offs2;

function mouseCoords(e) {
    x = e.x
    y = e.y
    if(cl1 === true){
    document.getElementById(divid).style.top= y-offs1+"px";
 document.getElementById(divid).style.left= x-offs2+"px";
 }
}
var drag1 = function(i, cas) {
 divid= i
 if(time1=== true){
  cl1= true
  time1= false
 }else{
  cl1= false
  time1= true
 }
 switch(cas){
  case 0:
   offs1 = 0;
   offs2 = 0;
  break;
  case 1:
   offs1 = y;
   offs2 = x;
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" onmousedown="drag1(1, 1);" onmouseup="drag1(1, 0);" style="background-color: yellow; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: fixed;"></div>
```

The first time there are no hiccups, but all proceeding times, the offset isn't close enough to the mouse to function almost seamlessly. How do I make the script work like it does the first time, every time? (It doesn't show up as much in the snippet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added considering current div coordinates. It seems to work more stably:

```js
document.onmousemove = mouseCoords;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var cl1= false;
var divid;
var offs1;
var offs2;
var _top;
var _left;

function mouseCoords(e) {
    x = e.x
    y = e.y
    if(cl1 === true){
  document.getElementById(divid).style.top = _top + (y-offs1) + 'px';
  document.getElementById(divid).style.left = _left + (x-offs2) + 'px';
 }
}
var drag1 = function(i, cas) {
 divid= i
 
 switch(cas){
  case 0:
   offs1 = 0;
   offs2 = 0;
   cl1= false;
  break;
  case 1:
   var rect = document.getElementById(divid).getBoundingClientRect();
   _left = rect.left;
   _top = rect.top;
   
   offs1 = y;
   offs2 = x;
   cl1= true;
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" onmousedown="drag1(1, 1);" onmouseup="drag1(1, 0);" style="background-color: yellow; width: 500px; height: 300px; position: fixed;"></div>
```